# How to write a partial deduction guide for class template argument deduction

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction, ctad

I am trying to write a deduction guide, that only detects one of many typename's from given constructor argument and requires user to enter `int` `size` manually

```cpp
template <int size, typename T>
struct Board
{
            array<array<T, size>, size> values;

            explicit Board(const vector<T>& raw_values){

            }
};
template <int size, typename T> Board(const vector<T>&) -> Board<int size, T>;
```

The idea above is that user should still be forced to enter "`int size`" argument of template, but "`typename T`" should be deduced from the argument of constructor, is this possible?

After correct specification, this is how method should be called

```cpp
auto b = Board<3>(initialStateVector);
```

Currently, it requires to me to enter like this;

```cpp
auto b = Board<3, int>(initialStateVector);
```

So basically, I want "`int`" above to be deduced from given `initialStateVector`, which has type

```cpp
const vector<int>& raw_values
```

Comment: `vector::size()` can only be known at runtime. You can't convert a vector to an `std::array` without knowing the size before hand.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks for answer, I know size of vector, it is 3, what i am trying to do here is not really about vectors though, Im trying to eliminate the need to specify int in Board<3, int>.

Comment: Does `Board<3>(initialStateVector)` give you a compile error? If so, what is it?

Comment: @Chipster It gives me a compile error at template <int size, typename T> Board(const vector<T>&) -> Board<int size, T>;  saying "typeid cannot have name"

Comment: That's weird. There's no `typeid()` in the code you posted. Maybe the error is another part of the code that you didn't post?

Comment: @Chipster code compiles and runs correctly when i remove that particular line

Comment: Hmm. That kind of makes sense.That line looks kind of broken. For one thing, you probably mean something like `Board::Board()` instead of just `Board()`. Why do you need that line? Is there a chance you can just remove it? It's not clear to me what benefit it is to you right now, since there is no implementation attached to it, and you implement the function in the struct declaration itself already anyway.

Comment: @Chipster I was trying to write a deduction guide for struct that only takes int size as template and deduces typename T from constructor's argument. Syntax itself is wrong and i was curious if there is a way to achieve what i wanted to do, it seems to be not possible

Comment: Can it not deduce it without the line? It looks like it should be able to.

Comment: @Chipster It gives "too few arguments for template" error without that line

Comment: Hmm. I must just be wrong then. I'll have to research why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The idea above is that user should still be forced to enter "int size" argument of template, but "typename T" should be deduced from the argument of constructor, is this possible?

According a note (and following examples) in [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

> Class template argument deduction is only performed if no template argument list is present. If a template argument list is specified, deduction does not take place.

no, this isn't possible (not in C++17; we can hope in future versions of the standard).

If you want explicit the size and let deduce the type, the best I can imagine is pass through a good-old make_something function.

I mean something as follows (using `std::size_t` for the size, as in `std::array` and almost all STL)

```
template <std::size_t S, typename T>
Board<S, T> make_Board (std::vector<T> const & v)
 { return {v}; }

// ...

auto b = make_Board<3>(initialStateVector);
```

that should works also in C++11.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, It is interesting that it can partially detect template's and take explicit size value in methods, but not on structs. Hopefully partial deduction guide's get added at some point in future to eliminate the need for make_x functiond

Comment: "*we can hope in future versions of the standard*" I wouldn't hold my breath; it was proposed and rejected for C++20.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm very interested to read more about this. Got any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a workaround using a size hint object

```cpp
template<int size>
struct SizeHint {};
```

Your class would take this as an additional constructor argument:

```cpp
Board(SizeHint<size>, const std::vector<T>& raw_values)
```

You call the constructor like this:

```cpp
auto b = Board(SizeHint<2>{}, v);
```

---

#### Bonus

This approach also works for type hints *(my original motivation how I found this thread)*:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct TypeHint{};

template<typename Result, typename T>
struct S {
    S(TypeHint<Result>, T arg) : t{arg}{}
    Result r() {return t;}
    T t;
};

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    S s{TypeHint<int>{}, 5.7};
    std::cout << s.r() << std::endl;
}
```

This can also be used in combination with variadic templates:

```cpp
template<typename Result, typename... Args>
struct S {
    S(TypeHint<Result>, Args... args) : t{args...}{}
    std::tuple<Args...> t;
};
```