# Partial emplate Argument Deducion C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code:

```
template <class B, class A>
class C {

    A m_a;

public:

    explicit C(A a) : m_a(a) {}

};

int main() {
    C<int>(16);
    return 0;
}
```

that can not be compiled. My purpose is to automatically deduce class A using the constructor parameter but use manually mentioned class B. Is it possible?

Comment: What is the purpose of `B` if it is not used?

Comment: There is no partial CTAD in C++.  You either specify none of the arguments or all of them.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX this is an example, B is used but can not be deduced from the constructor

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you'll find plenty of related SO posts. One example is : [C++17 Partial Deduction Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351144/c17-partial-deduction-guide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but only with a helper function.

As currently written, `C<int>` has to be the complete name of a type, which it obviously isn't. The constructor argument isn't considered until after the type of the object is determined.

So write

```
template <class B, class A>
C<B,A> make_c(A a) { return C<B,A>{a}; }

int main() {
    auto c = make_c<int>(16);
```

and now you have a function template whose second type parameter can be deduced as you want, from the argument, *before* you have to write out the type it returns.

Comment: So the difference is that partial arguments deduction is ok for usual function and not for the constructor?

Comment: You can't invoke the constructor until you know the type you're constructing, so the type you're constructing can't depend on the the constructor. It's a circular dependency. Having a separate function just breaks this loop.